# Calculate chromatic polynomial of this graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I want to calculate the chromatic polynomial of this graph:

[image]

I have tried removing one of the edges that connect the vertex with only $2$ neighbours but I don't think I am doing it right. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Hard to know if you're doing it right when you haven't shown us what you are doing?  What specifically is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this is correct because the Deletion-Contraction formula takes a while to do manually and I may have made some mistake, but this is what I've got:

$P_G(x)=x^6-10x^5+43x^4-94x^3+100x^2-40x$

I applied the "adding edges" version of the DC formula, and I arrived at the polynomial of $K_6+5K_5+8K_4+4K_3$